# Extracting anchor text from anchor tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, anchor

I recently posted on question for extracting anchor text from anchor tag using javascript. I got one answer for it.

However the code is working in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
function extractText(){
    var docId = "10";
    var cId = "13";
    var dName = "ASPIRIN/COUMARIN";
    var anchText = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=hello?docId=" + docId + "&cId=" + cId +">" + dName +"</a>";
    var str1 = document.createElement('str1');      

    str1.innerHTML = anchText;
    var anc = str1.innerText;

    alert(anc);

    return anc;
}
```

I suppose the property of `innerText` or `innerHTML` or both is not working in firefox. Can you please help where the above code work for IE, Chrome, Firefox etc.

Comment: i tried textContext and something caled textcontent.. is ther spelling error? or what else can be used?

Comment: using jQuery will help you get rid of these cross browser issues.
Any particular reason you want to stick with Javascript?

Comment: yes. it is an enhancement in existing codein our project. i hv restriction to use only javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't seem to support the `innerText` property, preferring to use the W3C's standard of `textContent`:

```
function extractText() {
    var docId = "10";
    var cId = "13";
    var dName = "ASPIRIN/COUMARIN";
    var anchText = "<a target=\"_blank\" href=hello?docId=" + docId + "&cId=" + cId + ">" + dName + "</a>";
    var str1 = document.createElement('str1');

    str1.innerHTML = anchText;
    var anc = (str1.innerText || str1.textContent);

    console.log(anc);

    return anc;
}

extractText();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jRY7u/).

Assuming you want to avoid checking both properties on every call, you could simply check which the browser supports, with:

```
var textProperty = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
```

And then use that as follows:

```
var anc = str1[textProperty];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jRY7u/1/).

References:

- [`innerText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Comment: var textProperty = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText'; var anc = str1[textProperty]; is working fine for me. Thanks you very much

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! Do consider, if your problem is solved, marking this answer as 'accepted' (by ticking the checkmark besides the answer text). Please see: '[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)'

Answer (score 0):

[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Node.textContent) by the W3C standard used in Firefox is the alternative for `innerText`